# Why does this series converge to the mean?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, recursion, mean-square-error

I am trying to understand why a specific series converges to the following result, in the context of an optimization problem.

We are given $N$ samples of the variable $y$. We want to find an $x$ that minimizes the mean square error. Thus, the recursive equation becomes:

$$
x_t = x_{t-1} - \lambda_t (x_{t-1} - y_{i_{t-1}}) 
$$

where $y_{i_{t-1}}$ is the $i$'th sample $y$ that is chosen at time instant $t-1$ during this optimization.

At any rate, I am told that if we let $\lambda_{t} = \frac{1}{t}$, then the final solution $\hat{x}$ converges to:

$$
\hat{x} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}y_j
$$

What I cannot figure out, is how we attain this conclusion? Why is it necessary for $\lambda_{t} = \frac{1}{t}$ for this solution to show itself?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use induction to show that $x_t = (y_1 + \cdots + y_t) / t$ for $t \ge 1$.

Comment: @arkeet How do you mean? What I am trying to understand is the relevance of the $\lambda_t$ here... thank

Comment: Well, the proof that $x_t = (y_1 + \cdots + y_t)/t$ depends on $\lambda_t = 1/t$. I guess I'll try to spell it out in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways to show this, one way is the following. Assume that $$y_n = x + \epsilon_n$$ where $\epsilon_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is IID.

If you observe $N$ samples of the above, you can write the log-likelihood equation you're trying to solve as:

$$ L(x^*) = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N (y_n - x^*)^2$$

which implies that $$L'(x^*) = \sum_{n=1}^N (y_n - x^*) = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N y_n = x^*$$ and
$$L''(x^*) = -\sum_{n=1}^N 1 = -N $$

Now, using a first-order Taylor expansion of $L'(x_N)$ around $L'(x_{N-1})$, where $x_N$ denotes the optimal $x$ at time $N$ we get:

$$L'(x_N) = L'(x_{N-1}) + L''(x_{N-1})(x_N - x_{N-1})$$

Since $x_N$ is optimal at time $N$, the LHS equals zero and we can re-arrange to show:

$$x_N = x_{N-1} + [L''(x_{N-1})]^{-1}L'(x_{N-1})$$

However, since $$L'(x_{N-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^N (y_n - x_{N-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (y_n - x_{N-1}) + (y_N - x_{N-1}) = (y_N - x_{N-1})$$
and $$[L''(x_{N-1})]^{-1} = -\frac{1}{N}$$

we see that $$x_N = x_{N-1} -\frac{1}{N}(y_N - x_{N-1})$$

**All we've done is taken the maximum likelihood solution and rearranged it to be in recursive form. So $\lambda = t^{-1}$, in your notation, is an outcome of the MLE process. It is commonly referred to as the Fisher Information matrix, and it tells us how much more info we learn about the true value of $x^*$ when we observe a new data point**

Comment: Very enlightening! I will need to read through carefully and digest it, but I think I get the jist... One thing though, shouldn't the $N$ be $n$ when you do the taylor expansion?... It's not the last index $N$ you are referring to, right?

Comment: Hmm, i used the notation $x_N$ to mean the optimal value after observing $N$ observations. Another way to write it could be $x_{new}$ vs $x_{old}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Im not following some of the $n$ and $N$s that are being used - are you sure they are consistent in usage here? Thanks...

Comment: sorry, I had some $x_{n}$'s in there that were typos. They should all be $x_{N}$ or $x_{N-1}$. I think i've fixed them all now

Comment: I think there is one more in the equation under "LHS equals zero...." ? I am just trying to be consistent so that I can understand. :)

Comment: No you're right, sorry again! Will change asap. Wrote tmy answer perhaps too quickly.

Comment: Hi measure_theory, thanks again for this answer. I had a moment to parse it over the weekend, however I am still confused about a couple things: 1) The usage of $N$ both as the optimal value at iteration $N$, AND as an index of in the summation is really throwing me off. There seems to be a mix up between the index of a sample used during the optimization, and the index of optimization itself. 2) In the equation right underneath the "However if...", I do not understand why this part is true: $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (y_n - x_{N-1}) + (y_N - x_{N-1}) = (y_N - x_{N-1})$. Thank you again.

Comment: Would it help if I re-wrote the optimal value of $x$ at time $N$ as $x^{N}$? If you observe $y_n$ from $n = 1$ to $n = N$, then your optimal  value of $x$ after observing $y_N$ is going to be the solution to $L'(x^N) = \sum_{n=1}^N (y_n - x^N) = 0$. Note again that $x^N$ just denotes the optimal value at time $N$, or after observing $N$ values of $y_n$.

Comment: By the same reasoning, the optimal value of $x$ at time $N-1$ will be the solution to $L'(x^{N-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (y_n - x^{N-1}) = 0$. So, if you substitute in $x^{N-1}$ into $L'(x^N) = \sum_{n=1}^N (y_n - x^N)$ you get $L'(x^{N-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^N (y_n - x^{N-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (y_n - x^{N-1}) +  (y_N - x^{N-1}) = (y_N - x^{N-1})$. The reason this is true is that we just showed that $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} (y_n - x^{N-1})=0$, since $x^{N-1}$ was optimal at time $N-1$.

Comment: Ok let me take another look over lunch.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\lambda_t = 1/t$ gives
$$x_t = x_{t-1} - \frac{1}{t} (x_{t-1} - y_t) = \frac{t-1}{t} x_{t-1} + \frac{1}{t} y_t. $$
In other words, $tx_t = (t-1)x_{t-1} + y_t$.
Then we can show by induction that $tx_t = \sum_{j=1}^t y_j$ for $t \ge 0$.

First, it is clear that this is true for $t = 0$. Now assume for induction that $(t-1)x_{t-1} = \sum_{j=1}^{t-1} y_j$. Then by the above equation,
$$tx_t = (t-1)x_{t-1} + y_t = \sum_{j=1}^{t-1} y_j + y_t = \sum_{j=1}^t y_j,$$
which is what was to be shown.

---

We have shown that $x_N = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N y_j$, assuming $\lambda_t = 1/t$. Then, by the law of large numbers, $x_N$ almost surely converges to $E(y)$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, let me study it today...

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!